# Specifying optional (default) parameter in procedure in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to write a procedure in Inno setup code using default values for parameters, like in Pascal, like
Procedure MyFunction(string1: string; string2: string = 'None');
begin
//Do nothing
end;

When I try to compile this, I get [...]
Compiling [Code] section

Compiler Error!
Line 10: 
Column 55:
Semicolon (';') expected.

Can anyone find out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Default parameters, overloads, etc.. are not supported in *"Pascal Script"*, the scripting engine that Inno Setup uses.

Comment: Is there some reference where you picked that from?

Comment: @hakre - I don't think it was an official reference, otherwise I'd link it. All I recall now is that I'd found something to feel confident about the answer, although I knew that was the case before searching. Feel free to not to trust. :)

Comment: Lolz, nah, was just asking while stumbling over it. It does not sound too far off ;)

Comment: Still the case in 2017. This time it wasn't PEBCAK!